# css/jquery: add margin-top and keep the current position

Tags: jquery, css

How can i keep the current view position if i add a margin-top to the first element on a page?
I don't want to see my page moving down ;-)

(how) could this be solved with jquery?

```
<body>
    <div id="add-margin-later">...</div>
</body>
```

Comment: And why would you add a margin if not to move the element, and wether or not the rest of the elements move depends on position !

Comment: so you want the body to move with the content as you add a margin? because thats easy, but your question is worded oddly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever the margin gets added to the element, in the same function set the window to be itself + 10.

```
$(window).scrollTop($(window).scrollTop()+10);
```

If you time this with the change, it should appear to remain in the same position. If you animate the margin add then just animation the scrollTop for the same duration.